# Is $\frac{\partial^2_xf \partial_yf}{\partial_xf}$ a total derivative?

Tags: calculus, functional-analysis, functions

Say $f$ is a function of two variables $x,y$. Is $\frac{\partial^2_xf \partial_yf}{\partial_xf}$ a total derivative? Or can we show $\int dx dy\frac{\partial^2_xf \partial_yf}{\partial_xf}$ vanishes?

Answer (score 0):

$ \frac{\partial^2_xf \partial_yf}{\partial_xf}$ is a quotient of partial derivatives and not a total derivative.

In general $\int dx dy\frac{\partial^2_xf \partial_yf}{\partial_xf} \ne 0$.

Example: if $f(x,y)=e^xe^y$, then $ \frac{\partial^2_xf \partial_yf}{\partial_xf}=e^xe^y$.